# If the absolute value of every eigenvalue of a matrix is smaller than 1, is the maximum singular value smaller than 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values

I am just curious. If the absolute value of every eigenvalue of a matrix is smaller than 1, is the maximum singular value smaller than 1? This is related to my previous question [Any relation between the singular values of ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf I} - {\bf A}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462312/any-relation-between-the-singular-values-of-bf-a-and-bf-i-bf-a). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a general $\mathbf A$, this is not true. Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Its eigenvalues are zero but the maximum singular value is 4. In general the spectral radius of a matrix is a lower bound on the operator norm of the matrix which means:
$$
\sigma_{\max}\geq |\lambda_\max|.
$$